# Get query results in ranges Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am running a query and it is too large. How may I retrieve the results in sections?
For example, 1 million rows at a time.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [`CURSOR`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/declare.html)

```
DECLARE my_curosor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ....

FETCH FORWARD 5 FROM my_cursor;
FETCH FORWARD 5 FROM my_cursor;
...
CLOSE my_cursor;
```

---

Another simplistic approach is to use  `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses.

Comment: This is the correct answer but I would encourage you to use UNLOAD if you are returning a large number of rows. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unloading_data.html